# I try to take some web values and try to insert them in to list . but list is not increase

Tags: python, list, while-loop

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


anc = 0
print(type(anc))

def executeSomething():

    global anc
    abc=0
    xyz=0




    quote_page = 'https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/eur-usd'
    page = urlopen(quote_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    instructions = soup.find("div", {"data-field": "Mid"})
    time2 = soup.find("div", {"data-field": "MidTimestamp"})

    print(time2.get_text(strip=True))


    print(instructions.get_text(strip=True))

    abc = float(instructions.get_text(strip=True))
    print (type(abc))


    time.sleep(400)

    instructions = 0
    instructions1 = 0
    quote_page = 'https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/eur-usd'
    page = urlopen(quote_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    instructions1 = soup.find("div", {"data-field": "Mid"})
    time3 = soup.find("div", {"data-field": "MidTimestamp"})
    xyz = float(instructions1.get_text(strip=True))
    print(type(xyz))
    print(time3.get_text(strip=True))
    print(instructions1.get_text(strip=True))
    fark = abc - xyz
    print(fark,"fark")
    data = []
    anc += 1
    print(anc)
    data.append(xyz)
    print(data, "data")




    if abc==xyz:
        print(abc,"if icinde")
        print(xyz,"if icinde")
        print ("degerler aynı")
        data = []
        anc += 1
        print(anc)
        data.insert(anc, xyz)
        print(data, "data")
    else:
        print ("degerler farklı")
        print(abc, "if icinde")
        print(xyz, "if icinde")



while True:

    executeSomething()
```

Result is:

```
<class 'int'>
07:09:00 AM
1.1205
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
07:16:00 AM
1.1205
0.0 fark
1
[1.1205] data
1.1205 if icinde
1.1205 if icinde
degerler aynı
2
[1.1205] data
07:16:00 AM
1.1205
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: can you add more information, e.g. what you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 0):

Looking just inside the `executeSomething` function, you set `data`  back to an empty list inside the `if abc==xyz` block, which is why `data` still only has one element in it the second time you print it.

Also, `data` is set back to an empty list each time the function runs. If you want it to accumulate, you should initialise it outside of the function and remove the `data = []` inside the function (both places)

Comment: thanks it works when I put the list outside the function